# eq selector not working

Tags: jquery, css

Two h3 elements are selected with the following selector:

```
$("#content div div ul h3").css("border","1px solid red");
```

I need to replace those elements as follows:

```
$('#content div div ul h3:eq(0)').replaceWith('<div>Top 5 Photos </div>');      
$('#content div div ul h3:eq(1)').replaceWith('<div>Recent Photos</div>');
```

The problem I am having is that both elements ( eq(0) AND eq(1) ) are getting replaced with "Top 5 Photos", and I cannot figure out why and how to fix this.

I will greatly appreciate any help with fixing this problem.

Comment: Without seeing your markup it would be guessing but it seems that you would only have 1 h3 per #content div div ul.

Comment: Paste your HTML markup please.

Comment: Bear in mind, once you've replaced `:eq(0)` with a `<div/>`, the second selector won't include that `h3` in the list of elements (as it's now a `<div />`).

Comment: Useless question without HTML.

Comment: thats correct I do have 1 h3 per #content div div ul. I apologize for not posting html, I do not have the html, i am working on a website that is using a template so I don't really have access to the code, otherwise I could modify it wihtout jquery.

Comment: @MHZ it doesn't matter if you can change the HTML; we need to see the output so we can help fix your selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#content div div ul h3:eq(0)').replaceWith('<div>Top 5 Photos </div>');      
$('#content div div ul h3:eq(0)').replaceWith('<div>Recent Photos</div>');
```

This answer seems to hazard, but it is right I think, because, when you first replace the `h3` with `div` then the second `h3` becomes `first` i.e `eq(0)`. So you can't never get a h3 with index 2 i.e `eq(2)`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pvgyt/)**

You can also try this:

```
var replaces = ['<div>FIRET</div>', '<div>SECOND</div>'];
$('#content div div ul h3').each(function(index, val) {
    $(this).replaceWith(replaces[index]);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TRKJu/1/)**

Comment: nope that does not work b/c we're replacing the same element twice. I appreciate the reply though.

Comment: @MHZ See the DEMO and then decide .

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `li`

```
$('#content div div ul li:eq(0) h3').replaceWith('<div>Top 5 Photos </div>');      
$('#content div div ul li:eq(1) h3').replaceWith('<div>Recent Photos</div>'); ​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YRJST/2/)

---

Or remember that you just replace one h3 tag:

```
$('#content div div ul h3:eq(0)').replaceWith('<div>Top 5 Photos </div>');      
$('#content div div ul h3:eq(0)').replaceWith('<div>Recent Photos</div>'); ​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YRJST/3/)

Comment: No I need to replace both because I am adding different styles to both, I just simplified the div for my post, to make it easier.

Comment: #content div div ul h3 is the correct selector, I don't need the li added to it.

Comment: Ah, did you try the second example I posted? It should work without adding the LI

Answer (score -1):

try this;

```
$('#content div div ul h3').eq(0).replaceWith('<div>Top 5 Photos </div>');
```

also check the quantity;

```
console.log($('#content div div ul h3').size());
```

Comment: The `.size()` method is functionally equivalent to the `.length` property; however, the `.length` property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.

Comment: size() is not heavy and cross browser. that's why i don't prefer to use ,length for dom collections, only for strings, arrays, etc.